# In a Heroku pipeline that's connected to Github, is it possible to configure automatic deployments from the API? what about manual deployments?

Tags: heroku, heroku-api

I'm referring to the actions of setting an automatic deploy or triggering a manual deploy in this UI:

[image]

Is it possible to change those values using [Heroku's Platform API](http://heroku.github.io/platform-api/PlatformAPI.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed with Heroku customer support that this is impossible. There's no API that allows you to change the branch that is autodeployed and there's no API that allows you to deploy a specific branch. There's an API to deploy a tarball, but that's not the same thing.